# Android: ViewPager items are String, but how can I access the Fragments?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've had a lot of `OOM` errors in the last couple of days, and I changed my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` entries to a String array.

```
public class AdapterProfiles extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   private ArrayList<String> mIds;

   public AdapterProfiles(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> ids) {
      super(fm, ids);

      mIds = ids;
   }

   @Override
   public FragmentProfile getItem(int position) {
      return FragmentProfile.newInstance(mIds.get(position));
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return mIds.size();
   }
}
```

The problem now is that when I want to access the current visible fragment, I'm getting a new instance of the fragment instead of the already attached fragment.

```
private FragmentProfile getCurrentProfile() {
   return (FragmentProfile) adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

So I have tried this way:

```
private FragmentProfile getCurrentProfile() {
   return (FragmentProfile) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

And now I'm getting `NullPointerException`.

What can I do in this case?

**Note**: I'm having 3 fragments in offscreen: `setOffScreenPageLimit(3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to find a fragment by the "android:switcher" tag works with `FragmentPagerAdapter` but NOT with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Because, it does not tag it's fragments.

Calling `adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem())` will not work sometimes if the adapter has not already cached the fragment at that index, you'll get a new instance.

To be able to get the selected fragment, the way I have done it is to override `setPrimaryItem` and store that in your adapter as the current object:

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    mSelectedItem = object;

    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}
```

This has worked well for me so far. I have also written a FragmentPoolPagerAdapter, which instead of destroying and restoring fragments, it recycles the fragments for re-use as pages are swiped. This adapter has a built-in mechanism to provide the app access to the selected fragment.